# PLSQL Why did my procedure did not detect insertion of duplication data?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a stored procedure which will insert employees information into 2 different table. When I run the script the first time, it will allow me to insert the same information twice, which is wrong, as it is supposed to trigger that there is duplicated data. But when I run again then it will only trigger the duplicated data error.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INSERT_EMPLOYEE(eNum IN NUMBER,
                    eName VARCHAR2,
                    dob DATE,
                    addr VARCHAR2,
                    hDate DATE,
                    lNum NUMBER,
                    status VARCHAR2,
                    expr VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
    INSERT ALL
        INTO TRKEMPLOYEE (E#, NAME, DOB, ADDRESS, HIREDATE)
        INTO MECHANIC (E#, L#, STATUS, EXPERIENCE) VALUES (eNum, lNum, status, expr)
    SELECT eNum, eName, dob, addr, hDate
    FROM dual
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
             FROM TRKEMPLOYEE 
             WHERE E# = eNum AND
                   NAME = eName AND
                   DOB = dob AND
                   ADDRESS = addr AND
                   HIREDATE = hDate);
END INSERT_EMPLOYEE;
/

EXECUTE INSERT_EMPLOYEE(17, 'Keban Tyz', TO_DATE('22-JAN-2019','DD-MON-YYYY'),'Sunshine Plazza     
#4-567 S891011', sysdate-(1.5*365), 10124, 'AVAILABLE', 'EXPERT');

-- error supposed to trigger here, but my script allow this to execute on the first run
EXECUTE INSERT_EMPLOYEE(17, 'Keban Tyz', TO_DATE('22-JAN-2019','DD-MON-YYYY'),'Sunshine Plazza 
#4-567 S891011', sysdate-(1.5*365), 10124, 'AVAILABLE', 'EXPERT');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `SYSDATE` when executing your procedure. `SYSDATE` has dynamic value, i.e. changed with every execution. Try to use some stable date in procedure parameter (for example, similar to your `TO_DATE('22-JAN-2019','DD-MON-YYYY')`) and it should work fine.

Additionally, you can add unique constraint to your `TRKEMPLOYEE` table (if it's not expected to be huge).

Answer (score 0):

i guess this is because you are generating hire date from sysdate(sysdate-(1.5*365)) and directly comparing it in filter condition(HIREDATE = hDate). try using only date part by truncating.